# Is there a way in HTML or JavaScript to make a redirect with something like anything.com and then after that is a input from the user?

Tags: javascript, html

So I use Bootstrap and stuff, I created a form control so I could have the user input something like "/random.html" and it could go to a certain website using  and add the input to the end of the website link, however I do not know how to do this and I could not find it anywhere on the Internet.

So what I expect is the user to input something like "/random.html" and then it goes to the site I want with the user input at the end.

Comment: Just assign the string to `window.location.href`?

Comment: try `let mySite='www.example.com' location.href=mySite+userInput;`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
function Redirect(){
   var userInput = document.getElementById("txtBox").value;
   var url = "https://yoursite.com" + userInput;       
   window.location.href = url;
}
```